# Jenkins docker image issue

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to build a image using the original jenkins docker repository but cannot run it. It throws an error saying ": invalid option".

Comment: Can you post the command/script you are using? Thank you

Comment: @gengisdave to build the image : docker build -t orig

Comment: To run the image: docker run -p 2000:8080 -p 50000:50000 orig

Comment: what exactly are you trying to build? Can you post the Dockerfile? Also, do you get the error during build or during docker run? It would be best to post the full log of the error you are getting

Comment: For now I am using this to build the image: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker . It can create the image but when I try to run I get this error. Also it seems that the error is related to running the entry point..